# What's the difference between "prime", "primary" and "primal"?

Tags: difference

From https://en.oxforddictionaries.com, I found they are very similar when used as adjective to describe importance:

> primal: Most important; primary or fundamental.
>
> primary: Of chief importance; principal.
>
> prime: Of first importance; main

Is there any differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certainly differences. What is very confusing is that you found three definitions that all mention "very important", which as such is correct in all three cases, but "very important" can have different connotations, as can your three words. If I leave out "important", my first associations with the three words are:

> primal: fundamental, instinctive: *primal fear*
>   primary: first in a sequence: *primary elections*, *primary school*
>   prime: very good / main: *prime location* / *prime suspect*

Comment: Thanks for you reply @oerkelens. But I am still a bit confused about primary and prime. Say, If I am buying a cell phone, and there're 3 choices. According to your answer, I would say "primary choice". But can I say "prime choice" because it's "very good"?

Comment: @TimothyZhang **Prime choice** would be understood as *"very important choice"* rather than *"very good choice"*, I think.

Comment: @TimothyZhang I think most people would go for _first_ choice in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@Oerkelens** concerning his definition, however, wish to add that:

- **Primary** and **Prime** are mostly interchangeable.
- **Primary** mostly means **"first in a group or series"** while **Prime** mostly means **"first in importance, degree, or rank"**
- **Primal** often means **"being the first in time, or history"** or **"being of greatest importance"**